# What database software will open a .db5 file?

Tags: database, windows-photo-gallery

What database software will open a .db5 file? Namely the Windows Live Photo Gallery Pictures.db5 database. I'd like to see the design and also the raw table data if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not because it has a .db5 extension that it means this is a database readable by other applications? I especially think it's NOT a dBase database.

It's most probably a proprietary format. Unless it's documented somewhere on MSDN, or reverse-engineered by someone, I doubt it can be read easily.

Answer (score 1):

I played with this a bit last year.  Assuming they've not changed the format for the 2011 version, it's a SQL Server Compact (.sdf) database.

The latest version is 3.5, I recall I had to convert it from 2.x before I could work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open DBase-Databases with Access (MSO) or Base (OOo), or any other tool which support ODBC-like connections.

Comment: Access 2003 reports that it's an "unrecognised database format". Is some kind of .db5 ODBC 'driver' required?

Comment: Try to create an empty access database and then import/connect to the db5 file. Sorry, but I've only seen this by a colleague, I don't have access. Also, as I think about, Calc (OOo) might be able tom open the file as Spreadsheet, at least it worked with db4 databases.

Answer (score 0):

db5 is a database format. There was an application called dBase-5, may be that created the ending...